# What happens to the rank when finding if a test-statistic is even?

Tags: order-statistics

When I take $X_1,...,X_n$ from $F(x)$. Then the ranks are $X_{(1)}<...<X_{(n)}$ and lets take the test-statistic,
\begin{align}
 t_0(X_1,...,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)}
\end{align}

If I look at $t(-X_1,...,-X_n)$ to see if $t(-X_1,...,-X_n)\overset{?}{=}-t(X_1,...,X_n)$, does the rank change?

For example is then $-X_1,...,-X_n$ correspond to $X_{(1)}<...<X_{(n)}$?

Sorry I am struggling to find the right way to ask this question.

**EDIT**

How about this test statistic,
\begin{align}
 t_1(X_1,...,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot X_{(i)}
\end{align}
Because I am wondering if the actual ranks change when I change their input values in $t_1(\cdot)$.

Is $t_1(-X_1,...,-X_n) = -t_1(X_1,...,X_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your test statistic is simply $$t(X_1, \ldots , X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{(i)} = \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i} = n \overline{X}_n$$ If you flip the signs of each summand then you get $t(-X_1, \ldots , -X_n) = - n \overline{X}_n$.

Comment: I get that let me append the question.

Comment: Take a look at my addition please, I am wondering mostly about the rank change rather than that specific test statistic.

Comment: @Tsangares Please don't modify questions after you've received answers to your original question.